# Linking to modules in external directory Compaq Visual Fortran command prompt

Tags: compilation, linker, fortran, compiler-directives, intel-fortran

I know that this question is VERY specific, but I am using "Compaq Visual Fortran Optimizing Compiler, Version 6.5" (Fortran 90). To compile, e.g., I use:

```
f90 constants.f90 main.f90 /compile_only
```

And I'm not sure how to link aside from using the command "DF", but as far as I understand, that compiles AND links AND outputs a .exe to be executed.

My problem is that I have a few modules that I USE in my main program, and I want those modules to be in one folder and my main program to be in another, but, when I try to use directives like -i dir to link the program and the used modules, they don't work and I get the following error:

```
error: Switch '-i' is ambiguous.
```

Any help, even just pointing me in the right direction, is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried /I (capitalized) or /Include?

Comment: Type **f90 /help** to see all the compiler options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Read your compiler manual](http://jp.xlsoft.com/documents/intel/cvf/cvf_pg.pdf)

> /[no]include
>
> Syntax:
>
> /include[:path...], /noinclude, or /Ipath
>
> The /include or /I option specifies one or more additional directories (path) to be
> searched for module files (USE statement) and include files (INCLUDE
> statement).

Comment: very simple and helpful answer. And it turns out that I can even just include the path before each file if I want. One difficulty though was that was running into errors with the "/" character, since it indicates when options are used. Thank you @Peter!

Comment: Also, @Peter, might you know why this doesn't work? :

Comment: df magneticField /exe:magneticField /include:..\FORTRAN_LIB\ __constants myIO griddata_mod myfdgen myDiff

Comment: It turns out that this is not actually working for me, from my comment above, my path is somehow not being found.

Comment: I would say this is an answer to your question about not found `-i` flag. Post another question or do some research if you have another issue. Quite unclear what your problem is from the comments

Comment: I did post another question, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23642360/compiling-and-linking-to-used-modules-in-external-directory-compaq-fortran-comma

Comment: Although I don't get an error using /include[:dir], it doesn't seem to do anything... I'll check this solution once the other question is answered, because reading the compiler manual was definitely a helpful start, but I don't feel like this solves my problem